# Milis to seconds JS binary search

Tags: javascript, search, binary-search, seconds

i was just practicing the binary search algorithm, and i wanted to know how much time it takes to finish in terms of seconds.

Is the way i treat startMilis and endMilis the correct way to get that time measurement? thanks.

```
let ar = [3,4,6,7,4,3,2,1,5,8,7,6,4,3,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(binarySearch(ar, 7));

function binarySearch(arr, value){
    let startMilis = Date.now();
    let endMilis = 0;

    let sorted = arr.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b;});    
    let high = sorted.length-1;
    let low = 0;
    let mid = 0;

    //console.log("input array sorted to: "+sorted);

    while(low <= high){
        mid = Math.floor( (low+high)/2 );
        
        if(sorted[mid] == value){
            endMilis = Date.now();
            return `${value} found at index: ${mid} in ${(endMilis-startMilis)/1000} seconds`;
        }
        else if(sorted[mid] < value) low = mid+1;
        else if(sorted[mid] > value) high = mid-1;
    }

    endMilis = Date.now();
    return "The requested value was not found, duration: "+(endMilis-startMilis)/1000+" seconds";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure performance of specific function, wrap it with profiling code to get the unbiased results. For example:

```
console.time('binarySearch');
binarySearch(ar, 7)
console.timeEnd('binarySearch');
```

Another thing I'd recommend here is separating the concerns. Your function should only return a value found (and some special value for 'not found' cases), and that's all. Logging some metrics (like speed, or memory, or whatever) should not be attached to that returned value.

With this approach, it'll be far easier to use platform-specific profiling tools (even as simple as console.time/timeLog/timeEnd) for *their* sole purposes - profiling.

*As a sidenote, you actually should not sort the source array, as it's in-place sort; unless there's a strong reason, you should avoid such side effects as modifying your functions' parameters.*

Comment: Thank you, yes about the return values and the logs, i get what you mean. After all i was just practicing the algorithm itself. 

About the array sorting tough, when implementing a binary sort, should i always assume that the source array is already sorted?

Comment: @J.Albert Yes, that's what I'd suggest here. In fact, that's how Lodash authors did it, too: they separated [binary search on sorted arrays](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortedIndex) from [plain search on array of unknown sequentality](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findIndex).

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you can also put start and end points outside the function so you won't have to worry about handling all returns

```
let ar = [3,4,6,7,4,3,2,1,5,8,7,6,4,3,5,6,7,8,9];

let startMilis = Date.now();
console.log(binarySearch(ar, 7));
let endMilis = Date.now();
console.log("search duration: "+(endMilis-startMilis)/1000); 

function binarySearch(arr, value){

let sorted = arr.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b;});    
let high = sorted.length-1;
let low = 0;
let mid = 0;

//console.log("input array sorted to: "+sorted);

while(low <= high){
    mid = Math.floor( (low+high)/2 );
    
    if(sorted[mid] == value){
        return `${value} found at index: ${mid}`;
    }
    else if(sorted[mid] < value) low = mid+1;
    else if(sorted[mid] > value) high = mid-1;
}
return "The requested value was not found";
```

}